# Difference between a bridge and just a cross over cable between two machines?

Tags: ethernet, layer1, cable

Is there a difference between a bridge and a crossover cable between two machines?

Comment: We need a little context. Why are you asking?   Operationally, there isn't any difference, but it depends on why you're asking.

Comment: @RonTrunk I'm asking because I want to learn about the difference between layer 2 and layer 3 in the OSI model, and I want to know if there's a difference.  (lame I know)  I thought maybe there might be a gateway with one, and no gateway with the other...but really I think that's layer 3 stuff.

Comment: A bridge is a network device that turns one collision domain into two collision domains. A crossover cable establishes one collision domain between two nodes. Neither of them are aware of anything that would be considered layer 3 in the OSI sense.

Comment: I think it would be more correct to say a bridge connects two collision domains.

Comment: Would recommend this article series on [how packets move through a network](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/packet-traveling/packet-traveling/). Specifically the article discussing Layer 2, Layer 3, and their differences and inter-operation, as well as the articles which describe host to host communication [through a switch](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/packet-traveling/host-to-host-through-a-switch/) and [through a router](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/series/packet-traveling/host-to-host-through-a-router/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  A crossover cable approximates a *hub* moreso than a *bridge* as the hub simply forwards all frames out of all ports.  The bridge will keep a mac-address table or bridge table and will forward frames to only those ports that see traffic from said host.

Comment: Yup, I tried it and it worked just fine.

Comment: OTOH a crossover cable allows full duplex while a hub doesn't.